# ZF2 complex SQL where closes

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db-select

How can I create complex WHERE closes in Zend\Db\Sql? 
Those with "COLLATE utf_general_ci" or "REGEXP".
Also what is the way to feed it the query as a string I want?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a full complex where clause would help but you can use Expression or Literal

**Initiate Adapter**

```
$adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'Mysqli',
    'database' => 'zend_db_example',
    'username' => 'developer',
    'password' => 'developer-password'
 ));

$sql = new Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($adapter);

$qi = function($name) use ($adapter) { return $adapter->platform->quoteIdentifier( $name ); };

$qv = function($name) use ($adapter) { return $adapter->platform->quoteValue( $name ); };
```

**Literal**

```
$regexSpecification = '(\\"key\\":\\"value\\")';
$sql->select()
        ->from('dbTable')
        ->where->literal( $qi('column1') . " REGEXP " . $qv($regexSpecification) )
        ->or->equalTo('column2', 'value');

//SELECT `dbTable`.* FROM `dbTable` WHERE `column1` REGEXP '(\"key\":\"value\")' OR `column2` = 'value'
```

**Expression**

```
    $expression = new Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression( "SHA2(".$qi('column2').", 512)" );
    $sql->select()
        ->from('dbTable')
        ->columns( array( 'hashed' => $expression ) )
        ->where( array( $qi('column1') . " COLLATE latin1_general_cs = " . $qv('value'))); 

//SELECT SHA2(`column2`, 512) AS `hashed` FROM `dbTable` WHERE `column1` COLLATE latin1_general_cs = 'value'
```

**Adapter Executed Query**

```
$adapter->query( 'ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX('. $qi('foo') .') ON ( '. $qi('foo_column') .' )', Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE );
```

**Referneces:**

https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html

https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html

Comment: Thanks @fyrye! I've figured out the literals by myself, but this will definitely help others around.